# How to send an email with an attachment via AIR for Android?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, email, air

I am making an Android app with Flash CS5. I am trying to send information from the app to the user with an E-Mail message. The information is all text, however, just plain text isn't enough. I'd much prefer using HTML formatting or some other way to better show it to the user.

Is there a way to send an attachment or at least include HTML formatting inside the body of an e-mail sent from AIR?

Right now I can send an E-Mails just fine with `navigateToURL(newURLRequest("mailto:ThisIsAFakeName@gmail.com));"`
I can also include a subject and body for the E-mail. However that is all plain text, and not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) should work. as far as i know it's the most common way for AS3 developers to send email attachments with Flash.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I need!