# I want to create something which records audio from the user and then allows them to send it to an email, OR save it to the server

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, record, microphone

I know how to use AS3 to record sound from the user and enable them to save it to their computer. However, I would really like instead to allow them to either send it to an email address right after recording (without them having to save it to their computer first and find the file), OR to let them save it so that the site owner can access it (They would know that it was happening.). How might this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of questions are generally discouraged in the community...the best questions to ask are how to accomplish/fix specific things, but not a general goal like this.

However, [this question may help you get started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7125347/472647). You will need to research the rest. Feel free to post a new question if you hit any specific problems in your code.